# The Sass ampersand and attribute selectors

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I want to create a sass file that the selectors will be attribute selectors.

When I work with class selectors, in most of the cases I will do

```
.parent {
    &-child {
    }
}
```

which gives me the following css: `.parent-child {}`.

I want to achieve the same thing with attribute selectors:

```
[data-parent] {
    &-child {
    }
}
```

which I want to become: `[data-parent-child] {}`

someone knows how to achieve this? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `mixin` as a workaround to get the desired result.

```
@mixin child-attribute($child) {
  $string: inspect(&);
  $original: str-slice($string, 3, -4);
  @at-root #{ selector-replace(&, &, "[#{$original}#{$child}]" ) } {
    @content;
  }
}
```

The code simply does the following

1. **$string** variable is responsible for turning the parent selector to a string using the `inspect` function
2. **$original** variable is responsible for getting the *text* content of the `$string` variable i.e the value `'data-parent'` from `'([data-parent])'`
3. **selector-replace** function then replaces the parent selector with the concatenation of the `$original` variable and `child` variable

When used in the following ways

```
[data-parent] {
  @include child-attribute('-child') {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

The css output

```
[data-parent-child] {
  color: green;
}
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, it can also be used like this

```
[grandparent] {
  @include child-attribute('-parent') {
    color: white;
    @include child-attribute('-child') {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Which generates the following css

```
[grandparent-parent] {
  color: white;
}

[grandparent-parent-child] {
  color: blue;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score -1):

You can create `mixin` that will set styles for elements with data attribytes.

Scss:

```
@mixin data($name) {
  [data-#{$name}] {
    @content;
  }
}

* {
  @include data('lol') {
    color: red;
  };
}
```

Css output:

```
* [data-lol] {
  color: red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b71cba8f388f207e9b7356b2f6f16ddf)**

Comment: this is no solution because `@include data('lol')` cant be parent selector and this misses all the purpose that is to create hierarchal code.

Answer (score -1):

I would go down a slightly different route of having a `class` on your elements that contain the `data` attributes.

`<div class="data-obj" data-parent="true"></div>`

`<div class="data-obj" data-parent-child="true"></div>`

then in your SASS do

```
.data-obj {
    ...

    &[data-parent] { ... }
    &[data-parent-child] { ... }
}
```