# Using CSS prefix selector with SASS ampersand

Tags: css, sass

In sass we can do some kind of class name concatenation with this:

```
//Sass
.button{
    &-1{ background-color: red; }
    &-2{ background-color: blue; }
}

//Result
.button-1{ background-color: red; }
.button-2{ background-color: blue; }
```

Can I somehow do concatenation on top of a prefix selector like this so that I don't have to use a base class or @extend:

```
*[class^="button-"]{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    &-1{
        background-color: red;
    }
    &-2{
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

I could achieve the same results with defining a base class and then adding specific styles after that like this:

```
.base-button{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.button{
    &-1{ background-color: red; }
    &-2{ background-color: blue; }
}
```

But I would then have to go and add that base class to all elements. 
Another approach is using the @extend directive like this:

```
.button{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.button-{
    &1{
        @extend .button;
        background-color: red;
    }
    &2{
        @extend .button;
        background-color-blue;
    }
}
```

I guess my question is if there is a particular reason why sass doesn't support class concatenation when the parent selector is a class prefix selector. Isn't it safe to make the assumption that the prefix used in the selector can be used for concatenation when that parent selector has nested classes with &? Or am I just doing something wrong with my sass?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SASS does a objective, literal concatenation when you use `&`, so:

```
*[class^="button-"]{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    &-1{
        background-color: red;
    }
    &-2{
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

will generate:

```
*[class^="button-"]{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
*[class^="button-"]-1{
    background-color: red;
}
*[class^="button-"]-2{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

which has invalid syntax, because a selector such as `*[class^="button-"]-1` is not valid CSS.

You can [create a mixin to get what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556519/the-sass-ampersand-and-attribute-selectors). But frankly, these solutions should be last last resort, like selector by an attribute other than class name or id. Even that, just KISS to keep readability and maintainability.